# How to avoid "Segmentation Fault" in c program

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I have written C program for Case Register. My program is working good. I used `-Wall` for compile. It didn't show any Warning.But the `problem is`, if I want to run it with `bash loop` such as `.test.sh | ./caseRegister`, the output is like the below:

```
:>>:1498.00
:>>:1499.00
:>>:1500.00
:>>:1501.00
:>>:1502.00
:>>:1503.00
:>>:1504.00
:>>:1505.00
:>>:1506.00
:>>:1507.00
:>>:1508.00
:>>:1509.00
:>>:1510.00
:>>:1511.00
:>>:1512.00
:>>:1513.00
:>>:1514.00
:>>:1515.00
:>>:1516.00
:>>:1517.00
:>>:1518.00
Segmentation fault
```

That test.sh is:

```
#/bin/sh

i=1
run=1
for ((; ; ))
do
echo $i
#echo $((i++))
done
```

Why my code is showing "segmentation Fault" for long run? Please anyone explain me the causes and prevention techniques to rectify it. Thank u in advance.

My Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
struct prod_details
{
    int no_prod;
    double total;
    double array[1024];
}pd;

char *getinput(char *inp)
{
    printf(":");
    gets(inp);
    if(strlen(inp) > 11)
    {
        printf("Input is restricted to 10 character\n");
        getinput(inp);
    }
    return inp;
}

void print()
{
    printf("Grant Total is : %.2f\n",pd.total);
}

int check(char *str)
{
    int i,minusflag=0,plusflag=0,optrflag=0;
    if(strlen(str) == 0)
        return 0;
    if(str[strlen(str) -1] == '+' || str[strlen(str) -1] == '-' || str[strlen(str) -1] == '*')
    {
        printf("last operator\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(str[0] == '-')
    {
        i=1;
        while(str[i] != '-' )
        {
            if(str[i] == '\0')
            {
                minusflag=1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(str[i] == '-')
        {
            minusflag=0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(str[0] == '-')

    {
        i=1;
        while(str[i] != '+' )

        {
            if(str[i] == '\0')
            {
                minusflag=1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(str[i] == '+')
        {
            minusflag=0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(str[0] == '-' && minusflag == 1)
        return 2;
    if(str[0] == '+')
    {
        i=1;
        while(str[i] != '+')
        {
            if(str[i] == '\0')
            {
                plusflag=1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(str[i] == '+')
        {
            plusflag=0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(str[0] == '+')
    {
        i=1;
        while(str[i] != '-' )
        {
            if(str[i] == '\0')
            {
                plusflag=1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(str[i] == '-')
        {
            plusflag=0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(str[0] == '+' && plusflag == 1)
        return 2;
    if(str[0] == '*')
        return 1;
    if((str[0] == '+' || str[0] == '-') && (str[1] == '+' || str[1] == '-' || str[1] == '*' || str[1] == '/'  ))
        return 1;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(((str[i] >= '!' && str[i] <= '/') || (str[i] >= ':' && str[i] <= '~')))
        {
            if(str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '/')
            {
                optrflag++;
            }
            else
                return 1;
        }
    }
    if(optrflag == 1)
        return 3;
    else if(optrflag > 1)
        return 1;
    return 2;
}

int expcalc(char *str)
{
    char copy[10];
    char op;
    char *temp;
    char numb[10],numf[10];
    printf("Start of expcal\n");
    int i;
    double result=0;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/')
        {
            op = str[i];
        }
    }
    strcpy(copy,str);
    i=0;
    while(str[i] != op)
    {
        numf[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    numf[i] ='\0';
    temp=strchr(copy,op);
    i=1;
    printf("\n");
    while(temp[i] != '\0')
    {
        numb[i-1] = temp[i];
        i++;
    }
    numb[i-1] = '\0';
    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
            result=atof(numf)+atof(numb);
            break;
        case '-':
            result=atof(numf)-atof(numb);
            break;
        case '*':
            result=atof(numf)*atof(numb);
            break;
        case '/':
            result=atof(numf)/atof(numb);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    printf("%.2f\n",result);
    if((pd.total+result) < 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't calculate\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pd.array[pd.no_prod]=result;
    pd.total=pd.total+result;
    printf(">>:%.2f\n",pd.total);
    pd.no_prod++;
    return 0;
}

int calc(char *str)
{
    if((pd.total+atof(str)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Coundn't Calculate\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pd.array[pd.no_prod]=atof(str);
    pd.total=pd.total+pd.array[pd.no_prod];
    printf(">>:%.2f\n",pd.total);
    pd.no_prod++;
    return 0;
}
int call()
{
    int chkflg;
    char input[1024];
    getinput(input);
    chkflg=check(input);
    if(chkflg == 3)
    {
        expcalc(input);
        call();
    }
    else if(chkflg == 2)
    {
        calc(input);
        call();
    }
    else if(chkflg == 1)
    {
        printf("You have entered Wrogly!!!\n Please enter correctly\n");
        call();
    }
    else
    {
        print();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("..CASE  RIGISTER..\n");
    call();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem in your code, most likely you are using a pointer that doesn't point to what you expect it to. Use a debugger to find out where and why.

Comment: I think we need to see the C code in order to answer this question.

Comment: Segmentation fault means your program accessed or executed invalid memory.  You've got a bug.  Seeing some code might help people analyze it but first you should run a debugger on it to see if you can figure it out for yourself.

Comment: set the limits with bash `ulimit` to get some `core` dump. Compile the program with `gcc -Wall -g`; use `gdb` and `valgrind`  to debug it. A segmentation violation shows that the program *is* buggy.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How to run gdb with bash loop?

Comment: `gdb` could be invoked in a bash loop, perhaps as `gdb --args yourprogram`. But most importantly, `gdb` can be invoked on a `core` dump. And you'll exit your `bash` loop if a `core` has been dumped...

Comment: Also compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g` and improve it till no warnings are given. Don't use `gets` -it is obsolete and dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.array only has room for 1024 results. You have to check that no_prod is < 1024 before writing to it, otherwise you'll write in unallocated memory, which is what gives you a segmentation fault. Once no_prod reached 1024 you have to abort the program (I assume you haven't worked with dynamic allocation yet).

It's good practice to not actually write 1024 at the check though, but rather use a macro for the array size (don't worry about this if you haven't used macros either).